# How to check and set grediant view in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cagradientlayer

I want to set gradient color to background on button click following is my code, i am getting crash on  **for case let objGrediantView as CAGradientLayer() in sender.subviews**

To check is there Grediant or not

```
func setGrediantView(sender: AnyObject, topColor: UIColor, bottomColor: UIColor){

    for case let objGrediantView as CAGradientLayer() in sender.subviews {
        if objGrediantView {
            // show error
            return
        }
    }


    let colorTop =  topColor.cgColor
    let colorBottom = bottomColor.cgColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = sender.bounds

    sender.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    let dicData = items[indexPath.item]
  //  self.objProfileView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
     self.setGrediantView(sender: objProfileView, topColor: (dicData["top"]!), bottomColor: (dicData["bottom"]!))
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Moreover, why do you say on button click and then you are calling it in `didSelectItemAt`?

Comment: actually its in collectionView's button action thats why, sorry for my english.

Comment: what's your crash?

Comment: when i am trying to check grediant layer is there or not that time i am getting crash

Comment: Yes, Thanks it solve my problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the text as this (your code is uncompilable, I really wonder how you got to it):

```
    for sublayer in (sender.layer.sublayers ?? []) {
        if sublayer is CAGradientLayer  {
            // show error
            return
        }
    }
```